# Trace of the underlying real linear map of a complex linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear endomorphism over a complex vector space $V$ ($\dim V=n$). Let $f^R:V^R\rightarrow V^R$ be the underlying real linear map ($\dim V^R=2n$) ($V=_{\text{Set}}V^R$). Suppose we know $\mathrm{trace}(f)$. Can we deduce the value of $\mathrm{trace}(f^R)$?

Answer (score 0):

Claim: $\mathrm{trace}(f^R)=2\operatorname{Re}\mathrm{trace}f$

Proof:
Let $\{e_i\}$ be a basis $V$. $\{e_i\}\cup\{ie_i\}$ is a basis of $V^R$. Let $f(e_i)=\sum a_{ij}e_j$. $\mathrm{trace}(f)=\sum_{i}a_{ii}$. $f^R(e_i)=\sum \operatorname{Re}(a_{ij})e_j+\operatorname{Im}(a_{ij})ie_j$ and $f^R(ie_i)=\sum \operatorname{Re}(a_{ij})ie_j-\operatorname{Im}(a_{ij})e_j$, therefore $\mathrm{trace}(f^R)=2\sum \operatorname{Re}a_{ii}=2\operatorname{Re}\mathrm{trace}(f)$.